# WPF - FlowDocument - Stretch Table to Entire Width?

Tags: wpf, width, flowdocument, sizing

I have a DataTable containing an arbitrary number of columns and rows which I am trying to print out.  The best luck I've had so far is by putting the data into a Table and then adding the table to a FlowDocument.

So far so good.  The problem I have right now is that the Table only "wants" to take up about half of the document's width.  I've already set the appropriate values for the FlowDocument's PageWidth and ColumnWidth properties, but the Table doesn't seem to want to stretch to fill up the allotted space?

Comment: I've ended up using a FixedDocument to get this to work, but if anyone has some insight on using a FlowDocument, I'd still love to hear it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had some luck with this:  [How to set the original width of a WPF FlowDocument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5596523/how-to-set-the-original-width-of-a-wpf-flowdocument), although it only took up about 90% of the space.

Comment: Actually, the 10% unused space was because I added PagePadding="0.5in" to the FlowDocument, which was necessary to keep the page from being chopped off when I printed it.

Answer (score 6):

In order to set your FlowDocument contents to the full available widh you must first know the width of the page. The property you need to set that takes care of the content length is the **ColumnWidth** prop on the FlowDocument.

I usualy create a "PrintLayout" helper class to keep known presets for the Page width/hight and Padding. Wou can snif presets from Ms Word and fill more.

**The class for PrintLayout**

```
public class PrintLayout
{
    public static readonly PrintLayout A4 = new PrintLayout("29.7cm", "42cm", "3.18cm", "2.54cm");
    public static readonly PrintLayout A4Narrow = new PrintLayout("29.7cm", "42cm", "1.27cm", "1.27cm");
    public static readonly PrintLayout A4Moderate = new PrintLayout("29.7cm", "42cm", "1.91cm", "2.54cm");

    private Size _Size;
    private Thickness _Margin;

    public PrintLayout(string w, string h, string leftright, string topbottom) 
        : this(w,h,leftright, topbottom, leftright, topbottom) {
    }

    public PrintLayout(string w, string h, string left, string top, string right, string bottom) {
        var converter = new LengthConverter();
        var width = (double)converter.ConvertFromInvariantString(w);
        var height = (double)converter.ConvertFromInvariantString(h);
        var marginLeft = (double)converter.ConvertFromInvariantString(left);
        var marginTop = (double)converter.ConvertFromInvariantString(top);
        var marginRight = (double)converter.ConvertFromInvariantString(right);
        var marginBottom = (double)converter.ConvertFromInvariantString(bottom);
        this._Size = new Size(width, height);
        this._Margin = new Thickness(marginLeft, marginTop, marginRight, marginBottom);

    }


    public Thickness Margin {
        get { return _Margin; }
        set { _Margin = value; }
    }

    public Size Size {
        get { return _Size; }
    }

    public double ColumnWidth {
        get {
            var column = 0.0;
            column = this.Size.Width - Margin.Left - Margin.Right;
            return column;
        }
    }
}
```

next on your FlowDocument you can set the presets

**On Xaml**

```
<FlowDocument x:Class="WpfApp.MyPrintoutView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         PageHeight="{Binding Height, Source={x:Static local:PrintLayout.A4}}"
         PageWidth="{Binding Width, Source={x:Static local:PrintLayout.A4}}"
         PagePadding="{Binding Margin, Source={x:Static local:PrintLayout.A4}}"
         ColumnWidth="{Binding ColumnWidth, Source={x:Static local:PrintLayout.A4}}"
         FontFamily="Segoe WP"
         FontSize="16" ColumnGap="4">
      <!-- flow elements -->
</FlowDocument>
```

**By code**

```
FlowDocument result = new WpfApp.MyPrintoutView();   
result.PageWidth = PrintLayout.A4.Size.Width;
result.PageHeight = PrintLayout.A4.Size.Height;
result.PagePadding = PrintLayout.A4.Margin;
result.ColumnWidth = PrintLayout.A4.ColumnWidth;
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it helped me a lot. Just a minor correction: A4 paper size is 21cm x 29.7cm, A3 is 29.7cm x 42cm.